# Windows 10 File Explorer Search Not Working

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

Using Windows 10 Pro 64bit. When I type something in the top right Search box of the File Explorer nothing happens. However it does work in Safe Mode. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that can cause this problem.

You can try the following methods first to see if the problem can be solved.

1.Restart your computer

2.Restart Cortana / Search process

3.Modify Windows Search service

4.Restore indexing services

5.Run the built-in troubleshooter

For detailed information, you can refer to the [link](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-10-search-not-working-solved/).

Comment: Of course I restated my computer, and the Search service. I cannot Restore Indexing Service as I don't see it on the Services, and if it is in the Indexing Options in Control Panel then this does not work either - when I click on Indexing Options the dialog opens but only Advanced is active and that does not respond to being clicked, and the dialog itself says "waiting to receive indexing status". I ran the troubleshooter but that didn't solve anything

Comment: @Abi Regarding the fourth and fifth methods, are you referring to the steps in the reference link?     Besides, if the above methods do not work, at the end of the article, it also provides two additional methods. However, these methods can have a big impact. You can wait for a while, maybe others have a better solution. If there is really no other solution, you can try these methods.

Comment: when you say two more items at the end are you referring to regf091 "download the Microsoft Media Creation Tool and do an 'inplace upgrade' of Windows 10" ? I download this but it does not run (it starts asks if I allow this app to run in Windows and when I say Y it disappears).

Comment: I mean Reset and Refresh Windows 10. However, it is best to back up important files before doing these things. If this still doesn't work, I suggest reinstalling the system or waiting for someone else to give a better solution.

Comment: I tried Recovery / Reset this PC / Get Started does not respond

Answer (score -1):

### As a workaround, use Cortana

As per [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026289/windows-10-find-your-documents), the preferred method of Search in Windows 10 is Cortana, accessed by clicking the box on the bottom left-hand side of the screen where it says 'Type here to search'.

Type the name of a document (or a keyword from it) into the search box on the taskbar. You'll see results for documents across your PC and OneDrive under 'Best match'.